# Choice of Smoothing Kernel in ABC

Tags: bayesian, simulation, algorithms, approximate-bayesian-computation

In Approximate Bayesian Computation, one approximates an intractable likelihood by convolving it with some smoothing kernel $K$ as

\begin{align}
\ell^{\text{ABC}} ( x | \theta ) = \int \ell ( z | \theta ) \, K (x, z) \, dz.
\end{align}

Common choices for $K$ include $K(x, z) = \mathbf{I} \left[ d(x, z) \leqslant \varepsilon \right]$ and $K(x, z) = \exp \left( - \frac{d (x, z)^2 }{2 \varepsilon^2 }\right)$, where $d$ is some sort of distance-like function, and $\varepsilon$ is some 'tolerance / threshold' parameter.

My question is: in practice, what guides the choice of $K$? For example, which features of a problem should encourage a user to prefer a uniform kernel to a Gaussian kernel?

Ignore the choice of summary statistics, threshold parameter, and so on. I am aware of the 'model error' perspective of R. Wilkinson (as in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3355)), which is very useful in some circumstances. Have alternative perspectives arisen in the interim? e.g. are there purely algorithmic reasons to prefer a specific kernel?

Comment: The kernel must be upper bounded, I think.